# Rabbitmq logging options don't work with docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq docker image as my base image in my dockerfile. My dockerfile looks something like this, where I am supplying my own conf file

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.8-management
COPY rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
RUN chown rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf 
RUN mkdir /certs
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt rabbitmq_web_mqtt
ENTRYPOINT ["/workspace/start.sh"]
```

I am trying to provide logging options in my rabbitmq.conf file, where I am trying to log to file instead of console and activate log rotation.

```
log.file = rabbit.log
log.dir = /var/log/rabbitmq
log.file.level = error
log.console = false
log.file.rotation.size = 10485760
log.file.rotation.count = 5
```

The problem is that these options are not being picked up by rabbitmq and I can't find the log file under
/var/log/rabbitmq and logs are still being written to console.

Answer (score 1):

The `rabbitmq:3.8-management` sets output to console `RABBITMQ_LOGS=-`

I found that setting `ENV` variable `RABBITMQ_LOGS` effectively disables logging instructions in `rabbitmq.conf`

In your Dockerfile try setting `ENV RABBITMQ_LOGS=` (note that `RABBITMQ_LOGS=""` would not work)